# How do i add dashes till my cell value equals to five in vba

Tags: vba

How do i add dashes(-) til my cell value = 5, If my length character is not equal to five and i have a 4 character, **for ex A  B**... what i want it to do if i have cell value less then 5 then i want it to replace with dashes(-) till my cell length value reach to 5 character. Here is my Code and image... IMAGE will make more sense.. let me know if there is any confusion.[image]

```
  Sub xn()
  Dim x As Integer, lastrow As Long, a As Long, i As Long
  Dim xcell As String
     a = 1
     lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
        For i = a To lastrow
          xcell = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Value
            Do Until Len(xcell) = 5
             If Len(xcell) <> 5 Then
          Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & i) = Replace(xcell, " ", "_")
             Else
              Exit Do
             End If
            Loop
         Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: do not use `Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count` method, the problem of this method is that you do not receive the last row, you receive only count of used rows, so e.g. if you have empty rows (1:5) then you will receive `lastrow - 5`. the second problem is that usedrange means that the range used not only by values, but with formatting also, e.g. if your range with values in 1:10 rows, but you have colored cell (or cell with borders or whatever) in row 15 then function will return you 15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
Sub test()
    Dim lastrow&, i&, xcell$, z%
    lastrow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        xcell = Replace(Sheet2.Range("A" & i).Value, " ", "")
        If Len(xcell) < 5 And xcell <> "" Then
           z = 5 - Len(xcell)
           Sheet2.Cells(i, "C").Value = Left(xcell, Len(xcell) - 1) & _
                WorksheetFunction.Rept("-", z) & Right(xcell, 1)
        Else
           Sheet2.Cells(i, "C").Value = xcell
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This line isn't going to do anything unless there's already spaces padding the end of the string:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & i) = Replace(xcell, " ", "_")
```

You need to check the length, if it's less than five, add 5 - length characters to the end of it:

```
Sub xn()
  Dim lastrow As Long
  Dim i As Long
  Dim xcell As String

    lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        xcell = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Value
        If Len(xcell) < 5 Then
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & i) = xcell & String$(Len(xcell) - 5, "_")
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

You can also leave out the variable 'a' - it's basically a constant in the code you posted.